# Accessing a Promises Value outside of its context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I understand to access a value of a Promise, I will use the "then" callback attach to it.

However, I was wondering how I can affect the context outside of it?

```
let outsideVar = 0;
promiseA.then(value => {
    outsideVar = 1;
})
console.log(outsideVar); //0
```

As you can see I would like to change outsideVar to 1

[Edit] This question was to see if promises can affect global variables outside of it and if there were any possibilities to do that.

Unfortunately, it is not possible.

Comment: use `promiseA.then(value => {
    outsideVar = 1;
}).then(()=>{
console.log(outsideVar);});` The `console.log` is not waiting for the promise to finish.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: @JaredSmith What about using a closure?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet no. Closures deal with scope. The problem here is *time*. You can't eat the BigMac before you've even made it to McDonalds, no matter how fancy your method of transportation (unless it's a Tardis).

Comment: Very true, ok, thanks. I thought there was a way to manipulate outside objects via closure, but you're right it might change the value but not in the time needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't changing your `outsideVar`, it's that you're checking it way too soon.

The `Promise` is async, so you need to wait until it is complete to output.

```
let outsideVar = 0;
promiseA.then(value => {
     outsideVar = 1;
}).then(() => console.log(outsideVar));
```

Once you start using a `Promise`, you need to keep writing async code.

You could use `await` and `async`, if you're using a preprocessor like Babel with `es2017` presets.

There are some caveats with them though:

- You can't run it directly at the top-level, it'd have to be in a function marked `async`.
- The code is still running asynchronously, it just looks synchronous. Be aware of this difference or weird things will happen.

Here is the example:

```
let outsideVar = 0;    
const doSomething = async () => {
    await Promise.resolve(); // something that is async
    outsideVar = 1;
};

await doSomething();
console.log(outsideVar);
```

Comment: Darn. I thought it was possible. Should I investigate Async/Await to handle this?

Comment: `async` and `await` will give you some syntactical sugar to help with this, yes. I'll update my answer with an example of using them.

Comment: `await doSomething();` is invalid. You can only use `await` inside an `async` function (I know you are saying this in the text, but the example is still invalid).

Comment: Seems like the outsideVar enters the "doSomething" function context and does not affect the "global" outsideVar.

Comment: @Anraiki no, it *does* affect it, it is just not guaranteed to do so at any particular *time*, in this case the time your `console.log` runs. You are not alone in struggling to grasp this concept: it's hard for a lot of people, but until you do you are not going to be able to wallpaper over the difficulty with syntax. We talk about 'synchronous' vs 'async', but a better way to say it might be code that does not run *sequentially* from top to bottom. The `console.log` runs before the mutation, but the mutation still happens. Eventually.

Comment: @FelixKling Indeed, but it makes the example too clunky to show too many levels of functions. I wanted to boil it down to just one single example.

Comment: Given that there many people who have problems understand asynchronous behavior in JavaScript or how `async/await` works, I think it could be really misleading. Why not just write `doSomething().then(() => console.log(outsideVar));`?

Answer (score -1):

`

```js
let ousideVar = 0;

function promiseA(){
 return new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
  resolve();
 })
}

promiseA().then(function(){
 ousideVar = 1;
  //when promise resolved
  console.log(ousideVar) // 1  
})

console.log(ousideVar) // 0
```

`When your promise resolved your "outsideVar" replace with the new value inside of then.
Example:

```
let outsideVar = 0;
promiseA().then(value => {
outsideVar = 1;
})
console.log(outsideVar);
```

When promiseA calls it return a callback and your value replaced with the new one
`outsideVar = 1;`

Comment: `console.log(outsideVar);` will still show `0`.